# WebView doesn't load url and still blank

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a problem with a WebView - I try to load url but it is blank.

This is my code:

```
        FrameLayout(context).apply {
                this.layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
                this.addView(
                        WebView(context).apply {
                            this.layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
                            this.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                    this.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
                            webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                                override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
                                    return true
                                }
                            }
                            loadUrl("https://example.net")
                        }
                )
            }
```

And I see a blank screen after launch. If I comment webViewClient there will be browser opening.

So, how to resolve my problem?

P.S. I have an internet permission

Comment: If your Web page relies on JavaScript, that is disabled by default with `WebView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare updated my question, I miss it to add to my post

Comment: What is the purpose of FrameLayout

Comment: @ManojPerumarath it's a wrapper, I tried without frameLayout and an issue reproduces

Comment: Which LayoutParams.WHAT_EVER are you using?

Comment: This is an `AbsoluteLayout` and not a `FrameLayout`.